# SQL Diagram in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012

How can I create a diagram in visual studio 2012 like this one
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server Management Studio...

[image]

You'll get a popup about "support objects required for database diagramming". Click Yes

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2012 you can create a windows app project or web app project and add a new item in your solution's project called an 'Ado.net Entity Data Model"  You can then import a model from an existing database or create your own model.